# Como converter MM/dd/yyyy para dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Acho que pelo meu computador ser dos EUA ele sempre salva as datas no formato americano, enfim, tenho um Date Time Picker que no computador do cliente fica em formato brasileiro, porém quando ele salva esse dado o C# troca os dias pelos meses.

Ex: Caso o cliente queira salvar a data 09/03/2020 a data salva ser 03/09/2020

```cs
   Classes.VendasServicos vs = new Classes.VendasServicos();
                    Venda venda = new Venda();
                    venda.idCliente = int.Parse(cmbCliente.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    venda.carro = txtCarro.Text;
                    venda.placa = txtPlaca.Text;
                    venda.data = DtVenda.Value;
                    Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
                    conexao.conectar();


 var escolha = MessageBox.Show("O cliente efetuou o pagamento de R$" + preco + ",00 ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (escolha == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        int linhas = conexao.executar($"INSERT INTO Vendas(data, carro, placa, idCliente, pago) VALUES('{venda.data.ToShortDateString()}','{venda.carro}','{venda.placa}','{venda.idCliente}', 1)  ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int linhas = conexao.executar($"INSERT INTO Vendas(data, carro, placa, idCliente, pago) VALUES('{venda.data.ToShortDateString()}','{venda.carro}','{venda.placa}','{venda.idCliente}', 0)  ");
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remova o  `.ToShortDateString()` da sua query de inserção, o c# por si só com o objeto `DateTime` criado no formato certo irá armazenar a data no formato correto no banco de dados.

Answer (score -1):

Opa! Realizei os testes em outro computador, e oq eu constatei é o seguinte nao importa como esteja o DateTimePicker (MM/dd/yyyy ou dd/MM/yyyy) ele sempre vai inverter e trocar o dia pelo mes, sendo assim ele não salva a data coreta.
Fazendo esses testes descobri um outro bug, toda vez que eu vou salvar uma data anterior ou posterior ao dia de hoje ele da erro de conversao, porém nenhum desses dois erros ocorrem qdo eu estou testando no meu pc.